# Nginx installation dependencies error Ubuntu

Tags: nginx

Nginx installation error Ubuntu 18.04, should I have to install those dependencies (nginx-core,nginx-full..) manually?

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-core (< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7.1~) but it is not going to be installed
     
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question itself has answer, solved by running

> apt --fix-broken install